# Передача данных из формы в темизатор

Tags: drupal, php

Имеется самописный модуль поиска для drupal.
Вопрос как из функции my_search_submit передать массив в функцию выводящую инфу на экран.
Сочинение ниже. Точно должен быть нормальный способ, только не могу найти его.

```
   //Описание блоков
   function my_search_hblock($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()){
   switch ($op) {
   case 'list':
   $blocks[0] = array(
       'info' => t('Поиск GM'),
   );
   $blocks[1]= array(
       'info' =>t('Результат поиска'),
   );
   return $blocks;
   case 'view':
   switch ($delta) {
     case 0:
     $block['content'] = my_search_page();//форма для поиска
     break;
     case 1:
     $block['content'] = my_search_result_contents();//результат поиска
     break;
   }
   return $block;
   }
}

   //Сам сабмитер
   function my_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   //некоторый код
   container($keywords);
   }

 function container($result=NULL){
 /**
  * Это что-то типа контейнера 
  * Если в функцию передана переменная--то её данные заносятся в сессию
  * Если ничего не переданно--то из сссии извлекаются данные, сама сессия обнуляться.
  **/
    if(is_null($result)){
        $result=$_SESSION['result'];
        unset($_SESSION['result']);
        return $result;
    }elseif(!is_null($result)){
        $_SESSION['result']=$result;
    }
}
  function my_search_result_contents(){
    $result=container();
    $output = theme('search', $result);
    return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно вопрос закрыт. Пришёл ведущий программист и сказал, что сразу после сабмитера идёт хиадер. Так что данные реально надо впихнуть в сессию и юзать. Заодно показал схему работы формы в "Pro Drupal Development". Так же возник вариант всю работу с обработкой переложить на аякс или джейКвери, а сабмитер будет делать echo html`а. У кого есть права закройте тему, плиз.